# Rails App With Custom Domain on Heroku Redirecting to Random Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I'm helping a friend out with her Rails App, and this morning the custom domain started automatically redirecting to freelancer.com instead of the App. The automatically created Heroku subdomain, i.e. 'randomapp.herokuapp.com' is still working fine without any issue. No new changes have been pushed to the Heroku repo for approximately a week, and the custom domain worked fine for months - until this morning. Were we hacked? Maybe a problem with the DNS? Any insight is greatly appreciated as I'm not particularly well versed in this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain still set in the Heroku settings? If so, the problem has to be with your domain service configuration. You should check if your domain's CNAME entry still leads to the Heroku app. And change your password if there's anything suspicious going on.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer above - if your domain is correctly set within the Heroku application settings, it is likely to be a DNS issue.

You can verify if your still have a CNAME entry by using the 'dig' command on a unix/osx terminal, e.g. `dig yourwebsite.com`

Within the "answer" section, you should see a CNAME entry pointing to your heroku subdomain.